# Can I Remap Command+F in Safari?

Tags: safari, macos, shortcut

How can I remap <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search the current web page? In Safari it somehow is set as a shortcut for fullscreen, which drives me insane!

What I would like is to at least kill <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to act as a no operation or remap it to do text search in the page.

This is crucial to sort throught the posts of an assortment of comments under YouTube videos.

Comment: Default for fullscreen in Safari is cmd/ctrl/f - so something must already have overwritten it. Cmd/f doesn't fullscreen in Youtube for me.

Comment: any way to troubleshoot this? I can't find a way out of this dire predicament

Comment: What does it actually say at the bottom of the View menu? cmd/ctrl/f or just cmd/f? Not sure how to troubleshoot - unless you know you have some kind of key-replacer app running. Maybe look where Andrey says in his answer & see if there's already a replacement listed [there shouldn't be, by default]

Comment: Edit -> Find -> Find... off the safari top menu bar shows shortcut as cloverleaf F

Comment: & what does Fullscreen say, View menu?

Comment: ^ cloverleaf F. but it does not act like it. meaning it does not act on F when both cntrl and window keys are pressed simultaneously, It goes fullscreen when either ctrl or window(cmd) key is pressed (with f). sounds like a moronic bug in 10.12.5 or safari

Comment: Nevermind. What happens on ^cmd F and cmf F is different. What happens is that ^cmdF puts the page containing the playback window fullscreen. While cmd F and ctrl F puts the frame with the video (video itself) fullscreen. So I fullscreen shortcut seems to be irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60516/discussion-between-anton-tropashko-and-tetsujin).

Comment: PC keyboard. window is command in apple speak and ctrl is whatever is marked with ^ in apple shortcuts icons.

Comment: I'd test with an Apple keyboard to be certain it's not just an incompatibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:
[image]

```
System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts
```

Click `+` And select Safari as Application.

Then enter the exact name of menu command (In your case: `Find…`) and enter your preferred hotkeys (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on the screenshot)

Comment: somhow it works on this page but does not work on youtube page. go figure...

Comment: could it be some moron who wrote javascript at google took some liberty to disrespect macos system shortcuts?

Comment: not only that but ctrl + f works identically to %f : it gets me to fullscreen. duh!

Comment: In case somebody is wondering what the hell is "the menu item" or "menu command" or "menu" that many others and this particular answer refer to. Menu is the top bar of each program on mac, the one with "File", "Edit", "View" etc labels. Inside each of this label buttons you can see "menu items", which have "menu commands" showed on the right side.